# Removing documents from result set at the time of query and returning desired number of documents

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Let's take an example and then I will explain what am I trying to solve.

Suppose my mapping is as follows:

```
{
  "parent_id": { "type": "integer" },   
  "mydata": {
    "type": "nested",
    "dynamic": "strict",
    "properties": {
      "name": {"type": "string"},
      "location": { "type": "geo_point"} 
    }                     
  }
```

}

Here I want to find all documents (in pagination way = 10 docs per page) matching some criteria, but in that result set, I want to keep ONLY one best match the highest scored) document with unique `parent_id`. That means suppose in the result, there are five such documents which have same `parent_id`, then I will pick one of those based on the highest score among them. However, in the end, the pagination should ALWAYS return me the desired (say 10)  numbers of the result after the elimination. Is it even possible to do at the query time? I am using ES 2.3

Comment: Wouldn't `GET your_index/_search?size=1{...}` do what you want?

Comment: Jamie, that's not my question. I am not looking for 1 result

Comment: Do a `top-hits` aggregation with size 1 on that field.